# Blur or focusout not working correctrly js

Tags: javascript

I have dropdown block with many checkboxes. And try to do focus out (when outside click, block will close and do some functions). But when im changing checkboxes inside block, blur works too. How to fix that?

```
elems.forEach(el => { 
  el.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");

  el.removeEventListener("focusout", outside_click);
  el.addEventListener("focusout", outside_click);

  check_checker(el);
});

let outside_click = (e) => {
  let el = e.target.closest(".filter-select");

  console.log(el);

  if(!el) return;
  e.target.classList.remove("is-open");
  check_checker(e.target);
}
```

Comment: You need to assign `outside_click` before the loop. `let` variables are not hoisted.

Comment: Or use traditional `function outside_click` syntax. This is hoisted.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is `blur` in the posted code?

Comment: What do you mean by "blur works too"?

Comment: When im clicking on checkbox inside `el` block, outside_click is run too...

Comment: Checkboxes don't keep focus when you click on them. When you let go of the button, they lose focus.

Comment: focusout is a blur its similar events...  function outside_click i cant do this cuz remove event lisner will not work.

Comment: but why div lose focus? if checkbox inside?

Comment: Because focus is temporary for checkboxes, unless you're using the tab key to select the checkbox with the keyboard.